# How do I use series and parallel combinations of inductors and resistors to achieve a certain resistance+inductance?

Tags: inductor, inductance, reactance

I'm building a current driver for a load of characteristics 20mH and 5ohms.
I don't have the load with me so I'm trying to create it using inductors + resistors so I can test my driver ckt.

I have four 5mH inductors (highest I could find) and each has 10ohm resistance. I propose the following circuit, do you see any issues or have alternative recommendations? Important to note the incoming signal has a max frequency of 100Hz, so the contribution of the reactance to the inductors' impedance (Z = R + jwL = 10 + 2j) at 100Hz is not negligible. I can tolerate that for now. I can always tweak the driver signal later on once I'm testing with the load.

Also other tips like proximity of the inductors to each other (considering magnetic field effects) are fiercely welcomed. I'm not knowledgable in that area.

Thanks in advance :)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNojS4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: By your thinking if you replace R1 with 0 ohms you'll get a 'perfect inductor' with no resistance.

Comment: If only it were so simple, we'd be able to lower the effective coil resistance by simply adding an external resistor and reduce copper wire diameters to any arbitrary amount.

Answer (score 0):

Your test load is not the same as the "real" load, as the comments pointed out. If you ran CircuitLab simulations you'd see that the real load's impedance increases without limit as the frequency increases, while the test load impedance only goes to 5.71 ohms.  Both look like 5 ohms at DC. You should be able to get those results with simple mental checks.

It sounds like you're being too fussy in trying to exactly match the loads, but that depends on what you're trying to do. It would make more sense to test with some kind of worst-case load.

BTW, lower case omega represents the angular frequency which is 2 pi times the frequency in Hertz. Your "real" load impedance at 100 Hz is 5 + j12.56 ohms.

Mutual inductance is unlikely to be a problem, but it depends on what inductors you're using, what you're trying to do, and how close you'd like to pack them.

Comment: Yea I think worst case load is a good approach, I'll try that. Thanks!

As for the mutual inductance, I'm using these inductors that have coils around an iron core, and I was just planning soldering them in a row right next to each other-maybe 1/2" apart. What I should have asked is what parameters (inductance, type of winding etc) should I take into account when deciding clearance b/w the inductors.